# Why does the Fibonacci sequence produce a worst-case Huffman encoding?

Tags: co.combinatorics, optimization, it.information-theory, encoding

I noticed this in my Algorithms class, but just now got around to asking.

Comment: i don't understand. what does this mean ? is the alphabet here the set of all digits ?

Comment: Is the question essentially: why is a worst-case Huffman encoding obtained form the probability distribution $\phi$, $\phi^2$, $\phi^3$, $\phi^4$, $\ldots$, where $\phi$ is the golden ratio? (and with the last probability $\phi^k$ increased so the sum is 1.) This is certainly not going to give a good Huffman encoding, but is this really worst-case?

Comment: Googling "huffman fibonacci" gives a possibly related paper: http://arxiv.org/abs/cs/0410013

Comment: The question is not well-defined.  What do you mean by “worst”?

Comment: @Ito: The obvious definition of "worst" is the difference between the average codeword length of the Huffman code and the Shannon entropy of the probability distribution. I don't know if this is what the OP had in mind. See my next comment.

Comment: Change the probability distribution in my previous comment to start with $\phi^2$, so the sum is 1. This certainly produces a maximum depth Huffman encoding. I don't know whether that qualifies as worst. Certainly it isn't the worst, using the definition in my previous comment, if you are allowed probabilities close to 1. But maybe it's worst-case if you are restricted to distributions with probabilities $< \frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: (1) @Peter: That definition of “worst” sounds reasonable (under the restriction on the maximum probability of a symbol, as you wrote), and I think that that question is interesting.  (2) I had voted the question down because of the underspecification.  When the asker edits the question to clarify what “worst” in the question means, I will reconsider the vote.

Comment: If we don't get an answer from the OP in a few days, I'll revive the question by asking it myself.

Comment: By "worst", I mean maximum-height Huffman binary trees.

Comment: If that's your definition of worst, I think your question may be answered in the paper given in Joseph Malkevitch's answer (depending on exactly what you mean by the Fibonacci sequence).

Answer (score 7):

This paper may shed some light on the issues: http://www.springerlink.com/content/w32x70520k8jj617/

Comment: Its behind a paywall. :(

Answer (score 3):

The Huffman algorithm considers the two least frequent elements recursively as the sibling leaves of maximum depth in code tree. The Fibonacci sequence (as frequencies list) is defined to satisfy F(n) + F(n+1) = F(n+2). As a consequence, the resulting tree will be the most unbalanced one, being a full binary tree.